# Spring security 401 unauthorized. Looks like problem with filter or permitAll()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

//The problem solution in my first answer.

I wright simple Spring Security project and seem to be wrought right because I did it before and everything works good with almost the same code, but now I can not permit request by "/auth/login".

What interesting, that in config class http.antMatchers('/auth/**").permitAll, but I can get access only by path /auth/reg. /auth/login - return 401.

Maybe someone familiar with this problem and will be kind to help me to resolve this problem.

My Security Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private JwtEntryPoint entryPoint;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService,
                             JwtEntryPoint entryPoint) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.entryPoint = entryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private AuthenticationManager authManager;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder encoder;
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(AuthenticationManager authManager,
                          UserRepository userRepository,
                          RoleRepository roleRepository,
                          PasswordEncoder encoder,
                          JwtTokenProvider provider) {
        this.authManager = authManager;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.encoder = encoder;
        this.tokenProvider = provider;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody LoginForm loginForm) {
        Authentication authentication = authManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginForm.getUsername(), loginForm.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String token = tokenProvider.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        UserDetails userPrincipal = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token, userPrincipal.getUsername(), userPrincipal.getAuthorities()));
    }

    @PostMapping("/reg")
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@ModelAttribute RegForm regForm) {
        if (userRepository.existsUserByUsername(regForm.getUsername()))
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("This username is already taken! Choose another one!");
        User user = new User(regForm.getUsername(),
                encoder.encode(regForm.getPassword()),
                UploadFileUtil.getStoragePath(regForm.getFile().getOriginalFilename()));
        Set<Role> defaultRoles = new HashSet<>();
        defaultRoles.add(roleRepository.findRoleByUserRole(Roles.USER));
        user.setUserRoles(defaultRoles);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("User registered successfully!");
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

A reason was not in Security Configs, but in class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails. When you implements all methods including getters, they are by default returns false and null. So when I tried to get field from the principal they return null into Authentication, so passwords was not the same and I got response 401 unauthorized.

So do not forget to override the methods the right way and you won't waste your time for strange mistakes.

Thank you for everyone who helps, for no one.

```
public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

    private long id;
    private String username;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public static UserPrincipal build(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getUserRoles().stream().map(role ->
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getUserRole().name())
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new UserPrincipal(
                    user.getId(),
                    user.getUsername(),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    authorities
        );    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
```